# Semantic zoom out view is over lapping another zoom out view in windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml, semantic-zoom

I have 5 pivot item. in each i have semantic zoom in view and out view, when i make semantic zoom out view it overlapping another semantic zoom out view screen.
how to resolve this issue.

This is my code:

```
 <Grid Margin="0 -15 0 0" Grid.RowSpan="2" x:Name="MainGrid">
        <Pivot x:Name="PivotControl" x:Uid="PivotControlTitle" PivotItemLoaded="PivotControl_PivotItemLoaded"  Visibility="{Binding PivotControlVisibility}">
            <PivotItem Margin="20 10 15 10" Tag="0">
                <SemanticZoom  IsZoomedInViewActive="{Binding IsSZoomedInViewActive, Mode=TwoWay}">
                    <SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
                        <GridView
                        AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemsGridView"
                        AutomationProperties.Name="Grouped Items"
                        SelectionMode="Multiple"
                        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource fileItemControl}"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource groupItemViewSource}}"
                        IsSwipeEnabled="True"
                        >
                            <GridView.GroupStyle>
                                <GroupStyle HidesIfEmpty="True">
                                    <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <TextBlock 
                                                Padding="0 2 0 11"
                                                x:Name="GroupHeader"
                                                Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextBlockStyle}"
                                                Foreground="White" 
                                                Text="{Binding GroupName}"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                                    <GroupStyle.Panel>
                                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                            <ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0 0 20 0"/>
                                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    </GroupStyle.Panel>
                                </GroupStyle>
                            </GridView.GroupStyle>
                            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="SelectionChanged">
                                    <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding GridViewSelectionChanged}"  />
                                </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        </GridView>
                    </SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
                    <SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>
                        <GridView
                            Padding="18 0 0 0"
                            AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemsGridView"
                            AutomationProperties.Name="Grouped Items"
                            Background="#DD000000"
                            SelectionMode="None"
                            IsSwipeEnabled="True"
                            SelectedIndex="{Binding SZOutSelectedIndex, Mode=TwoWay}"
                            HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource SemanticZoomOutViewHeaderTemplate}"
                            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DefaultGroupOutViewItemTemplate}"
                            >
                            <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
                                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
                                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                                <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local"/>
                                <Setter Property="IsHoldingEnabled" Value="True"/>
                                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,7,4,4"/>
                            </Style>
                        </GridView>
                    </SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>
                </SemanticZoom>
            </PivotItem
```

> Above pivot control has 4 more pivot item like above one

Comment: Could you please post some snippets how your Semantic Views look like?

Comment: I have edited my post, please see the code have any issue

Comment: I have posted code can anybody tell me the solution why semantic zoom out view is overlapping